# Appending QList to QList<QList>

Tags: c++, list, qt, append, qlist

I have an interesting problem with Qt Qlist container.
Trying to append QList to QList makes my iterator to point to unknown part of memory.

```
QList<int> listSmall;
QList<QList<int>> listBig;

for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    listSmall.append(i);

for(auto it = listSmall.begin(); it != listSmall.end(); ++it)
    listBig.append(listSmall);
```

Condition `it != listSmall.end();` always true if i append small list to big.
Why does this happen?

P.S. STL list works just fine.

Comment: I don't have an idea about qt but check this link and see if u can find it useful          https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41438428/qlist-iteration-using-conditions

Comment: @Tharushi Geethma unfortunately that question just suggests using stl algorthms, but doesnt say what is wrong with appending to QList.

Comment: you just need to do `listBig.append(listSmall);` once if you want to append it!?

Comment: @xander This is not a real problem i have in my project, it is unclear behavior that bothers me

Comment: Your listBig is a list of lists? Is this intentional? If so, you might want to call append just once, not in a loop.

Comment: @ChristianG Yes, this is intentional. Yes i want to append it every time. Yes, i want to understand why my code works unpredictable, although it's written correctly.

Comment: Looks like a real bug. I ran the following code and it worked
 `QList<int> listSmall;
    QList<int> listSmall1;

    QList<QList<int>> listBig;

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i){
        listSmall.append(i);
        listSmall1.append(1);
    }

    for(auto it = listSmall1.begin(); it != listSmall1.end(); ++it){
        listBig.append(listSmall);
    }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known limitation of Qt containers when used with stl-like iterators. The [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/containers.html#implicit-sharing-iterator-problem) explains it.

> Implicit sharing has another consequence on STL-style iterators: you should avoid copying a container while iterators are active on that container. The iterators point to an internal structure, and if you copy a container you should be very careful with your iterators.

I am afraid you will have to find a different way of doing what you are trying to do (like using a standard list or iterate differently).

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: use `cbegin()` and `cend()` when you don't change values.

Details:

- Compiler calls non-const `begin()` and `end()` version just as you
  asked; it can use const versions if you call `cbegin()` or `begin()`
  through const ref/pointer.
- QList tries to be copy-on-write and shares memory instead when you do
  `listBig.append(listSmall);`.
- On next iteration inside non-const `end()` there is call to
  `detach()` which copies data after confirming that local data is
  referenced more than once (like, it is referenced by listBig content
  already).

All in all, that is a good example of why copy-on-write is hard to implement correctly.

[BugReport with answer](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-63882)